# SystemError: dynamic module not initialized properly, when import sub module under a sub folder

Tags: python, import, aes, pyd

I have an issue while importing a dynamic python module (`pyd`), my file structures is as follow:

```
A
|--A.py
+--B
  │--B.py
  │--__init__.py
  +--Crypto
     |--__init__.py
     +--Cipher
        |--__init__.py        
        |--_AES.pyd
```

A.py: `from B import B`

B.py: `from Crypto.Cipher import _AES`

when executing `A.py`, I get the following error:

```
SystemError: dynamic module not initialized properly
```

The import is working fine when I am executing `B.py`. Also, If I move `Crypto` to another place and add that folder to `sys.path`, the import is still working fine.

The error occurs when `B.py` and the `Crypto` are under the same folder, but `B` was imported by another file which is not under the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

After trying various factors, I think it's the module being appended with a relative path name.
This should be a bug caused by the python relative import feature

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).